# Check which users use forwarding and to which address

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, g-suite-administrator

I'm the admin for a Google workspace organization. A user has left the company but the mailbox remains active in order to send out auto-replies, informing senders that the user is no longer with the company.

Even though the user no longer has access to his mailbox, in theory, I guess it's possible that they have set up forwarding instructions to an external email address. Which is a security risk not just for leaving users.

Is there a way for me to check for all mailboxes in the workspace if such forwarding instructions are set and to which addresses?

Comment: would a possible solution be to send an anonymous email to the address vacated with a send receipt to see what happens to it?

Comment: Google Workspace Admin (https://admin.google.com) have a search box and a help assistant. You might have to start looking at the Google Workspace Admin Help Center, more specifically at the Get Started section in order to get familiar with the pretty basics including the teminology used in the app. If you still need help, please show what you have tried, what features and help articles you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Must read from Workspace Help Center : [Use your Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2413312?hl=en), [Email forwarding options for Google Workspace users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2707558?hl=en), [Manage Gmail settings for your users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173555?hl=en), [Monitor the health of your Gmail settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7490901?hl=en), [Advanced Gmail settings reference for admins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2786758?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén I'm not sure why you assume I didn't do all of this first. Yes, I checked the help assistant and yes, I spent time looking through the docs. What I could find is that I can turn the setting on or off but that wasn't my question. I also know that I could check the logs for any forwarded messages but that also wasn't my question. Users are allowed to forward but I'd still like to know if they have a forwarding instruction active and to where. And if that's not a valid question for SE, then I don't know what is.

Comment: @24601 Thanks but it wouldn't be my preferred approach. Then I'd rather simply disable forwarding altogether for the user.